# how to convert my unicode dictionary to plain text

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get my message to show up using jinja 2 in python and flask. The message is posted in the sql database and I want to retrieve it. so far my server.py file looks like this:

```
message_pull = mysql.query_db("SELECT messages.id, messages.user_id, 
messages.message, messages.created_at, users_table.first_name, 
users_table.last_name FROM messages JOIN users_table ON messages.user_id = 
users_table.id")
messages= mysql.query_db('SELECT * FROM messages')
print messages
return render_template('loggedin.html', messages = messages)
```

and my html page that corresponds to this app route looks like this:

```
<p>{{messages}}</p>
```

and it shows up on the web page like this:

```
[{u'created_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 14, 1, 58), u'message': u'We are posting for the first time out here!', u'user_id': 26L, u'id': 1L, u'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 14, 1, 58)}, {u'created_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 14, 32, 3), u'message': u'This is the second post', u'user_id': 26L, u'id': 2L, u'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 14, 32, 3)}]
```

How do I make it show up as a regular post without the dictionary format and the "u" in front of each key and value?

Comment: `encode` the unicode string.

Comment: Why is the database unicode if you don't want unicode data? It should not be. Having the same encoding inside and outside database will save your life.

Comment: Why are you showing the end user the structure of the data?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to solve this:

Don't encode the database in unicode, just store it as string information. It's not very user friendly, and the encoding / decoding step is just extra unnecessary work.

Or, presuming the following code is being run inside a method:

```
# i'm presuming the string data you provided is what's in this array
messages = mysql.query_db('SELECT * FROM messages')

# create a list to store our encoded messages in so we can return them
encoded_messages = []

for message in messages:
    # create a new dict to store the encoded information in
    message_info = dict()

    for key in message:
        if type(message[key]) == String:
            message_info[key.encode()] = message[key].encode()
        else:
            message_info[key.encode()] = message[key]

    # store our encoded message
    encoded_messages.append(message_info)

# return our info
return encoded_messages
```

To be honest, though, it's not a great idea to display data structures on a website. Unless you're super confident about the safety of your database, it's really insecure. (even then, it's not a good idea) Beyond that, it's not very user friendly to present data this way.

Reading back your question, I suspect you want to be able to present the data in some way as well. There are various ways to do this but the answer to that doesn't really belong here. I would suggest looking into the way various other websites do this.